# Javascript autocomplete stop for in loop

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, for-in-loop

I'm trying to build a simple autocomplete feature and I'm running into a problem with the following script

```
<input type="text" name="search" id="searchField" placeholder="search for something" />
<div class="results-list">
    <ul id="searchResults"></ul>
</div>


<script>
var users = JSON.parse('{{ $accounts }}'); // json data from php script

// add event listener
Event.add('searchField', 'keyup', function(){
    if(document.getElementById('searchField').value.length > 1) {
        processSearch(users, 'searchField', 'searchResults');
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('searchResults').innerHTML = '';
    }
});

function processSearch(data, field, result) {
    if(document.getElementById(field).value.length == 0) {
        document.getElementById(result).innerHTML = '';
    }
    else {
        for (var k in data) {
            if(data.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                if(data[k].indexOf(document.getElementById(field).value) != -1) {
                    var list = document.createElement('li');
                    list.innerHTML = data[k];
                    document.getElementById(result).appendChild(list);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Now I'm getting the right results but if I keep writing the results are getting reproduced and I end up with a lot of duplicate results like in the picture below

[image]

And when I'm deleting the results are still duplicating unless the length of the field is less than 1 and all results are getting deleted.
Would anyone be able to tell me how to stop getting the duplicates?

Comment: What is the JSON data that is being written by php?

Comment: its an object with multiple names from database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that as `processSearch()` is called on every keystroke, and you append the results all the time to previous results. You need the delete the previous results in the beginning callback, i.e. iterate over all children of the result element and remove them using `removeChild()`. And then you can add the new results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `for...in` statement for enumerated objects, but for iterating arrays, `for...in` should be avoided. Instead use the standard `for` statement.

```
for (var k = 0; k < data.length; k++) {
    if(data.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        if(data[k].indexOf(document.getElementById(field).value) != -1) {
            var list = document.createElement('li');
            list.innerHTML = data[k];
            document.getElementById(result).appendChild(list);
        }
    }
}
```